# ubuntu doesn't treat touchscreen input as touch (just left click)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, touchscreen

I have a ThinkPad X230T with multitouch-screen, and Ubuntu treats multitouch inputs as just 'clicks'.

Here's my `xinputs` outout:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom ISDv4 E6 Pen stylus                 id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger touch               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom ISDv4 E6 Pen eraser                 id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

(My latest attempt to get it working (just 10 minutes ago) was upgrading to Ubuntu 17.04.)

Any suggestions to make Ubuntu recognize touch-screen as touch-events?

The symptoms can be verified using the Qt multi-touch demo app and Google Chrome.

ere's some relevant `xorg.0.log` content:

```
[     8.420] (**) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger: Applying InputClass "Wacom tablet class"
[     8.420] (**) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger: Applying InputClass "Wacom touchscreen class"
[     8.420] (**) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger: Applying InputClass "evdev tablet catchall"
[     8.420] (**) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger: Applying InputClass "evdev touchscreen catchall"
[     8.420] (**) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger: Applying InputClass "Wacom USB tablet class"
[     8.420] (**) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger: Applying InputClass "Wacom USB touchscreen class"
[     8.420] (**) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger: Applying InputClass "Wacom tablet class"
[     8.420] (**) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger: Applying InputClass "Wacom touchscreen class"
[     8.420] (II) Using input driver 'wacom' for 'Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger'
[     8.420] (**) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger: always reports core events
[     8.420] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[     8.484] (EE) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger: Invalid type 'stylus' for this device.
[     8.484] (EE) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger: Invalid type 'eraser' for this device.
[     8.484] (EE) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger: Invalid type 'cursor' for this device.
[     8.484] (II) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger: type not specified, assuming 'touch'.
[     8.484] (II) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger: other types will be automatically added.
[     8.484] (--) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger touch: maxX=2776 maxY=1569 maxZ=0 resX=10000 resY=10000
[     8.484] (II) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger touch: hotplugging dependent devices.
[     8.484] (EE) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger touch: Invalid type 'stylus' for this device.
[     8.484] (EE) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger touch: Invalid type 'eraser' for this device.
[     8.484] (EE) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger touch: Invalid type 'cursor' for this device.
[     8.484] (EE) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger touch: Invalid type 'pad' for this device.
[     8.484] (II) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger touch: hotplugging completed.
[     8.524] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.1/0003:056A:00E6.0006/input/input11/event6"
[     8.524] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger touch" (type: TOUCH, id 11)
[     8.524] (**) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger touch: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[     8.524] (**) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger touch: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[     8.524] (**) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger touch: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[     8.524] (**) Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger touch: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[     8.584] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger (/dev/input/mouse1)
```

I'm not sure what the last line did, but that line looks suspicious. (`/dev/input/mouse1`?)

Comment: Use `xinput -test id_of_device` to see potential multitouch events, not all applications handle them. Is the Wacom an external device? Is the Synaptics TouchPad already using the synaptics driver, or still the default evdev? (Check in `Xorg.log`).

Comment: @dirkt for xinput -test id_of_touchscreen, I get rows of: "motion a[0]=1793 a[1]=969 a[2]=0 a[3]=0 a[4]=0 a[5]=0"

Comment: @dirkt could it be the Synaptics driver interfering with the touchscreen? I do have a touchpad on the tablet(though I usually disable it because it's annoying)

Comment: You still didn't say if Wacom is an external device. If it is, the Wacom entries are not relevant. You also didn't say what the ID of the touchscreen *is*, which would help in identifying the device. We can only debug based on the information you give us, if you don't give information, we can't help. First step is to *identify* the device that acts as touchscreen (Synaptics Touchpad, Wacom, both?). Second step is make sure it has the correct driver.

Comment: @dirkt oh... thought that was somewhat obvious...sorry for the confusion. anyway, the touchscreen device is wacom fingerprint (it's baked into the tablet screen - is that's what you mean by external/internal?)

And it's supposed to be a multitouch (windows gets it as multitouch alright)

Comment: Does [this information](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Multitouch) help?

Comment: @dirkt yep while reading your link, it suggested some stuff about xsetwacom & gesture settings. did xsetwacom --set <device> gesture off and it's working!!! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Please write down what you did as answer, so people with the same problem can find it. Comments may get deleted.